# Congruences mod p#

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Maybe the following can be done by induction or maybe there is some group-theoretical approach that I am unlikely to see. Thanks for any hints or thoughts.

> $(\cdot)$ is an exclusive interval. Let $p\#$ be the product of primes not exceeding $p.$ Let $q=p\#-p^2.$
>
> **Claim.** There is always an integer $n$ in $(1,2p)$ such that $n\not\equiv q $ mod $(2,3,...,p).$

To be clear, $n$ cannot have the same congruence as q mod any prime $\leq p.$ I am not sure what the term for that is and have been thinking of it as "co-mod" (comod). For example, 6 and 11 are coprime but both are congruent to 1 mod 5 hence not comod.

**Example.** Let $p=5. $ Then $q=(2\cdot3\cdot5)-5^2=5.$ Now $5\equiv (1,2,0)~$(mod $2,3,5).$ Because 5 is on the interval $(1,10)$ it is easy to check that $(5\pm1)$ both satisfy the requirement: $4\equiv (0,1,4)$ and $6\equiv (0,0,1)$  (mod $2,3,5)$ and both are $\not\equiv 5$ mod $2,3,$ or $5.$

**Induction** seemed like an approach that might work. In general we have a $q = (1,2,a,b,c,...,0)$ (mod $2,3,5,7,11,...,p$). Starting with 5 on the inteval $(1, 2p)$ we can imagine for small numbers how the position of $a,b,c,...$ can prevent non-congruence. For larger numbers the unknown quantities can begin to interact and so this seems obscure.

**Group theory?** There are probably group theoretical properties of comods that are beyond me. For example, coprimes to $5\#$ on $[1,5\#)$ seem to be a special case of comods in the sense that the comods to any number on $[1,30]$ give a partition of this interval into non-disjoint classes of 8 members, the comods/coprimes to 30 being the usual $(1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29).$ It also seems true that there are 8 natural groupings of these classes:(30,1), (2-7), (8-11), (12,13), (14-17),(18,19), (20-23), (24-29) but this is only meant as an indication of what I have looked at (without success).

Comment: not going to bump this--just to correct: there are 30 nondisjoint partitions and they do not form "natural groupings". this was an artifact of my listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to asking if there is always $m=n+p^2$ between $p^2$ and $(p+1)^2$ with $$m \equiv n+p^2 \not \equiv q+p^2 \equiv p\# \equiv 0 \pmod{2,3,...,p}$$
i.e. if there is always a prime $m=n+p^2$ between $p^2$ and $(p+1)^2$, which is [Legendre’s conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) restricted to the primes. Seems true, but probably an open problem.

Comment: Excellent observation!